# Integrable submartingale

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times, uniform-integrability

Suppose $X_n$ is a **uniformly** integrable submartingale and $T$ a stopping time. I wanna show that $X_T$ is integrable. To this end, I write $X_T=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k \mathbb{1}_{\{T=k\}}$. Now I would like to apply the dominated convergence theorem, but I  can't find a clearly integrable function that would upper bound each of the partial sums. Perhaps $\sup_n X_n^+$: but is the uniform integrability of $(X_n)$ enough to guarantee that $\sup_n X_n^+$ is integrable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that by uniform integrability, there exists a random variable $X_\infty$ such that $X_n\to X_\infty$ almost surely and in $L^1$. Moreover, for each non-negative integers $\ell$ and $k$, the submartingale property gives
$$
\mathbb E\left[\lvert X_T\rvert\mathbf{1}_{\{T=k\}}\right]=\mathbb E\left[\lvert X_k\rvert\mathbf{1}_{\{T=k\}}\right]\leqslant \mathbb E\left[\lvert X_{k+\ell}\rvert\mathbf{1}_{\{T=k\}}\right]
$$
and the convergence of $X_{k+\ell}$ to $X_\infty$ in $L^1$ shows that
$$
\mathbb E\left[\lvert X_T\rvert\mathbf{1}_{\{T=k\}}\right]\leqslant \mathbb E\left[\lvert X_\infty\rvert\mathbf{1}_{\{T=k\}}\right].$$
Summing all the inequalities over $k$ and using integrability of $X_\infty$ finishes the proof.

Comment: Just one question. Why does uniform integrability imply the existence of that $X_{\infty}$ to which $X_n$ converges P a.s.? Is it because uniform integrability implies $\sup_n E[X_n^+] < \infty$ and one can use the martingale convergence theorem?

Comment: Exactly, this is a consequence of the sub-martingale convergence theorem.